# Cannot figure out why appendChild is returning undefined

Tags: javascript

I cannot figure out why `appendChild` is returning undefined.

I also tried `t.previousSibling.appendChild(document.createElement('span'));` which returns "previousSibling undefined".

I need to add a span element with class of "error" to the span, withing the textnode of the label. So I loop through all the inputs and look for one that is empty, if it's empty, it should add "*required" message next to the input label. I've got lots of ideas, but not sure where the problem lies. THANKS for your help!

```
var obj = {

inputs: document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
btn: document.getElementById('submit'),

init : function() {

    obj.btn.onclick = obj.submitForm();

    },

submitForm : function() {


    for (var i=0; i<obj.inputs.length; i++) {

        if (obj.inputs[i].value==="") {

        switch(obj.inputs[i].name) {

            case "fname" : match=true; obj.error("fname");
            case "lname" : match=true; obj.error("lname");

            }   
        }
    }
},


error : function(t) {

        var err = "*required";
        var j = t.previousSibling.appendChild(document.createElement('span'));
        j.className = "error";
        j.appendChild(document.createTextNode(err));

    }   
}


Here is HTML: 

<head>
<title>Homework 9 JavaScript form</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
<div>
<ul>
<li><label>First Name</label><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" size="30"  /></li>
<li><label>Last Name</label><input type="text" name="lname" size="30"  /></li>
<li><label>Phone</label><input type="text" name="phone" size="30"  /></li>
<li><label>Email</label><input type="text" name="email" size="30" /></li>
<li><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</ul>
</div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="hw9.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">obj.init();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `error` method appears to expect a DOM object as an argument, but you're passing it strings. At least, the strings probably don't have a `previousSibling` property that would have an `appendChild` method.

You can either pass along the objects you're already checking against:

```
switch(obj.inputs[i].name) {
    case "fname" : // fall-through
    case "lname" : match=true; obj.error(obj.inputs[i]); break;
}
```

Or, you can change `error` to expect a string. Either an `id` -- if you give `<input name="lname">` an `id="lname"`:

```
error : function(id) {
    var t = document.getElementById(id);

    // ...
}
```

Or by a `name`:

```
error : function(name) {
    var t = document.getElementsByName(name)[0];

    // ...
}
```

Also, be sure to `break` each `case` that you don't want to fall-through into subsequent cases:

```
case "fname" : match=true; obj.error("fname"); break;
case "lname" : match=true; obj.error("lname"); break;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this makes sense. Hopefully some day when I know what I'm doing I can help other people too ;) Cheers.

Comment: Update: I got over this hump and now I should be able to get it functioning from here. Staying alive for another week in this class...

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question but a suggestion. In line:

```
>  btn: document.getElementById('submit'),
```

Never use an ID or NAME for any form control of "submit", it will mask the form's submit method so you can't call it. The only reason to give a submit button a name is if there is more than one in a form and you want to know which was used to submit the form.

Also, in the line:

```
>     obj.btn.onclick = obj.submitForm();
```

you are much better off to attach the listener to the onsubmit property of the form, not to the onclick property of the submit button. And you should be assigning a function reference, not the result, so:

```
  obj.btn.form.onsubmit = obj.submitForm;
```